# How to use Swift cocoapods in objective c project

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods

Hi i am working with `objective-c`,now i want to use `swift` in my project using cocoapods(3rd party libraries).Is this possible?

Comment: My experience says  **NO**.  We can use Objective-C Library in Swift using **Bridge Concept**

Comment: @iDeveloper Ok Thank you

Comment: @Bittoo Please read the answers in the linked page.